# Is there a more elegant way to write this in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function () {
 $('#button').click(function () {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(document).height()
     },
     400);
     return false;
 });

 $('#top').click(function () {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: '0px'
     },
     400);
     return false;
 });
});
```

I'm using that code to scroll to the bottom/top of the page. I'm wondering if there is a better way to write that? I'm new to jquery so I'm not sure but I've heard using `event.preventDefault()` may be better instead of `return false`? If so, where would I insert that?

Comment: return false; acctually calls event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() so no need to worry about that.

Comment: You got it right. Only thing is, you don't need to animate the `html` tag it's just enought to query for `$(document.body)`. The `return false` statement isn't necesarry in your case, no need to prevent the default button action or stop propagation.

Comment: try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using a [ternary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) to select the scroll? eg

```
$(function () {
  $('#button').add('#top').click(function () {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop : ((this.id=='button') ? $(document).height() : '0px')
     },
     400);
     return false;
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle for this code here](http://jsfiddle.net/bUvfK/)

You could make this better by adding a class eg `'navButton'` to each of these buttons and then using that as the selection ie [`$('.navButton')`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) - This will eliminate the `.add()` call.

Also I'd recommend giving the bottom button the id `bottom` rather than `button` :) eg

```
$(function () {
  $('.navButton').click(function () {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop : ((this.id=='bottom') ? $(document).height() : '0px')
     },
     400);
  });
});
```

Comment: As jAndy suggests I've removed the `return false;` also

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
$(function() {
  var map = {'#button': $(document).height, '#top': '0px'};
  jQuery.each(map, function(k, v) {
     $(k).click(function() {
      $(document.body).animate({
         scrollTop:(typeof v === 'function') ? v() : v
      },
      400);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I really consider this as degradatio (for such a easy task).

Comment: @Jacob Relkin: I just don't see the necessity to overcomplicate things on a requirement like this.

Comment: @jAndy, Yeah I understand - it does do it in less LOC though! - Also, it's DRY-er.

Comment: Moreover, if I'm not mistaken, this won't work correctly if the page size changes, as `$(document).height()` is calculated when the page is loaded, not during the click event. BTW, you need to interchange `'#top'` and `'#button'`.

Comment: @Marcel I see, how about now?

Comment: This looks better to me, but makes jAndy's objection even more valid: I have to think about what this code does, whereas the original code is way more clear.

Answer (score 0):

According to jQuery manual return false and preventDefault does different things:

Example: Cancel a default action and prevent it from bubbling up, return false:

```
$("a").live("click", function() { return false; })
```

Example: To cancel only the default action by using the preventDefault method.

```
$("a").live("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

So `preventDefault` is more limited.

Comment: This was in answer to one part of the question: `I'm new to jquery so I'm not sure but I've heard using event.preventDefault() may be better instead of return false?` which I at least thought was related, not a complete answer sure, but I thought i still could be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Using a specialized plugin [jquery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo).

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/1.4.11/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
```

Makes code nice and easy

```
$(function() {

$('#button').click(function() {
    $.scrollTo('max', 400);
    return false;
});

$('#top').click(function() {
    $.scrollTo(0, 400);
    return false;
});

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/disfated/mkZp3/

---

Also if you want a more flexible code, you could do something like

```
$(function() {

$(document).on('click', '[data-scroll]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.scrollTo($(this).data('scroll'), jQuery.fx.speeds._default);
});

});
```

Then, define scroll behaviour directly in html, example

```
<button data-scroll="max">scroll to page bottom</button>
<button data-scroll="0">scroll to page top</button>
<button data-scroll="#my_selector">scroll to #my_selector element</button>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/disfated/Sj8m7/